# Queue-based communication: is it a good idea to send a return-queue?

Tags: python, multithreading, message-queue

I was playing with the following approach to wait for the result of an asynchronous operation runnig in another thread:

```
def client(worker_queue, message):
    answer_queue = queue.Queue(maxsize=1)
    worker_queue.put((answer_queue, message))
    result = answer_queue.get(timeout=10)


def worker():
    while True:
        answer_queue, message = worker_queue.get()
        result = do_someting_with(message)
        answer_queue.put(result)
        worker_queue.task_done()
```

(The primitiv worker is only an example. In other cases it could be necessary to pass the "answer_queue" between multiple callbacks)

Is this a good idea, or will I run into problems (for example with memory management)?

Are there better ways to do this?

I know that `asyncio` has things like `futures` to handle problems like this, but for the moment I'm looking for something that (also) works multithreading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python uses memory addresses to access class variables and their methods. Using a queue simply ensures that each worker has a unique memory address location to place its answers.

Make sure, if the variable remains a local variable, that when you no longer need the variable, you reassign it, so garbage collection can release memory the queue was using, or clear memory using the `del` keyword to manually do it, such as `del answer_queue`.

You could use any data type to fulfill the role of transmitting the data between worker and client because all class methods are accessed by memory address; however, the most common ways of transmitting data are:

### Using Queues

`queue.Queue()` is already quite optimized and very versitile, so it is a reliable way of performing communication between clients and workers.

```
import queue
import datetime
from threading import Thread
def queue_client(worker_queue, message):
    answer_queue = queue.Queue(maxsize=1)
    worker_queue.put((answer_queue, message))
    result = answer_queue.get(timeout=60)
    print('Bytes received from worker:', len(result))

def queue_worker(worker_queue):
    answer_queue, message = worker_queue.get()
    do_something = lambda x: x[::-1]
    result = do_something(message)
    answer_queue.put(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    large_message = 'X' * (2<<30) #2GB

    worker_queue = queue.Queue()
    client = Thread(target=queue_client, args=(worker_queue, large_message,))
    worker = Thread(target=queue_worker, args=(worker_queue,))
    start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    client.start()
    worker.start()
    client.join()
    worker.join()
    dt = datetime.datetime.now() - start_time
    print('Time elapsed using Queue:', dt.total_seconds()) #~1.47 secs on my machine
```

#### Shared memory types

Since you have direct memory access to the variable addresses when multithreading, you can use shared memory; this is generally the fastest way to access the data, but you would need some kind of container object for the data.

An very basic example (worker spawning, answer submission, etc. could be added to the manager):

```
import datetime
from threading import Thread

class DataManager:

    def __init__(self,):
        self.tasks = {
            #worker_id: message
        }
        self.answers = {
            #worker_id: answer
        }

def shared_client(datamanager, worker_id, message):
    datamanager.tasks[worker_id] = message
    while not datamanager.answers.get(worker_id, None): #Wait for answer
        pass
    result = datamanager.answers[worker_id]
    print('Bytes received from worker:', len(result))
    

def shared_worker(data_manager, worker_id):
    while not data_manager.tasks.get(worker_id, None): #Wait for task to get assigned
        pass

    message = data_manager.tasks[worker_id]
    do_something = lambda x: x[::-1]
    result = do_something(message)
    data_manager.answers[worker_id] = result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    large_message = 'X' * (2<<30) #2GB
    data_manager = DataManager()

    worker_id = 0
    client = Thread(
        target=shared_client, 
        args=(data_manager, worker_id, large_message,)
    )
    worker = Thread(target=shared_worker, args=(data_manager, worker_id))
    start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    client.start()
    worker.start()
    client.join()
    worker.join()
    dt = datetime.datetime.now() - start_time
    print('Time elapsed using Shared Memory:', dt.total_seconds()) #~1.44 secs on my machine
```

More graceful (and potentially even faster) solutions may be available if you use shared memory types/ctypes such as Multiprocessing.Value and Multiprocessing.Array [(link)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value).

### Pipes

Pipes act as a connection with one end listening while the other is sending data.
Importantly, this behaves more favorably than queues while **multiprocessing** when sending packets larger than ~32MB. Additionally, it is serializable, unlike `queue.Queue()`.
A sample of using a Pipe:

```
import datetime
from threading import Thread
from multiprocessing import Pipe

def client(conn, message):
    conn.send(message)      #Send message to worker
    result = conn.recv()    #Receive result
    print('Bytes received from worker:', len(result))

def worker(conn):
    message = conn.recv() #Get message from client
    do_something = lambda x: x[::-1]
    result = do_something(message)
    conn.send(result) #Send result to client

if __name__ == '__main__':
    large_message = 'X' * (2<<30) #2GB
    client_conn, worker_conn = Pipe(duplex=True) #Bidirectional pipe
    client_process = Thread(target=client, args=(client_conn, large_message))
    worker_process = Thread(target=worker, args=(worker_conn,))
    
    start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    client_process.start()
    worker_process.start()

    client_process.join()
    worker_process.join()
    dt = datetime.datetime.now() - start_time

    print('Time elapsed using Pipe:', dt.total_seconds()) #~9.07 secs on my machine
```

### Proxy

Proxies register functions on a client and allow for their execution via a worker calling the underlying exposed function. This is a lot trickier, but necessary for cluster computing, when your workers are on different computers than your clients.

Comment: What if I have multiple-clients and multiple workers? The nice thing with my solution is that the client doesn't need to know how many workers are running, and the workers always send the result back to the right client. I only quickly played with your example, but Pipes seem to be much less flexible.

Comment: I submitted my answer addressing how this should be done with **multiprocessing**, not **multithreading**. I updated the answer to more appropriately reflect how else this could be done when multithreading.